# Slider interactive when making the first click the width is enlarged and when making the second click it directs to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I am needing help to be able to make a slider that is interactive with HTML and CSS, this slider must become wider when we click on it, I think that can be achieved with JavaScript, also with the second click it allows me to go to another window, what I don't know how to achieve is to make it larger as shown in the sample image and that the second click just takes it to another window, thank you very much. I attach a representative image.

[It would be like a carousel that is going to pass, as can be seen in the image]

so I was able to make this code that captures the click, it also sees which of the sliders is active but it doesn't work at all, I still haven't been able to make the slider look the right way, this is because it is difficult for me to make the carousel.

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let currentSlide = -1;

slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (currentSlide !== -1) {
            slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
        }
        if (currentSlide !== index) {
            slide.classList.add('active');
            currentSlide = index;
        } else {
            // Redirige a la página deseada en el segundo clic (simulado aquí)
            window.location.href = 'pagina_articulo.html';
        }
    });
});
```